# How do I translate this raw SQL query in PHP ActiveRecord?

Tags: php, activerecord, phpactiverecord

I'm trying to run this sql query as a php activerecord query:

```
 delete from article_categories where 
     article_id = 10
 and
     category_id in (1,4,5,6,7)
```

This statement works fine when I run it from the mysql console.

I tried doing this from php activerecord:

```
   $query["conditions"] =  array('article_id = ? and category_id in (?)', 10, "1,4,5,6,7");
   ArticleCategory::delete_all($query);
```

The problem is it is only deleting one record at a time.

I expect all the records that match

```
   article_id == 3
```

and

```
   category_id == 1 || category_id == 2 || ... || category_id == 5
```

to be deleted.

However only the first record with fields
       article_id = 3, category_id = 1

gets deleted.

What am I typing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use "IN (?)" in your where clause, be sure to pass an array as the condition value. Otherwise it would just read IN ("1,2,3,4") in stead of IN (1,2,3,4) (note the double quotes in the former version!).

So, it would look something like this:

```
$article_id = 1;
$categories = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
ModelName::delete_all(array(
    'conditions' => array('article_id = ? and category_id IN (?)', $article_id, $categories)
));
```

And if you just want to delete the current record, do:

```
$record->delete();
```

Be careful not to invoke ->save() afterward, because the record will be saved again.

Comment: yes, this may have come a bit late, but hey, better late then never, right?

Comment: Right on...who knows... I might need to solve this problem again in the future and have forgotten the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if the ID you're sending it to delete can be empty? [The documentation](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Basic_CRUD) shows this for "Massive Update or Delete".

```
  Post::table()->delete(array('id' => array(5, 9, 26, 30));
```

So, translated in your situation that would be something like

```
ArticleCategory::delete(array(array('id'        => array(1, 4, 5, 6, 7)),
                              'conditions'=> array('article_id = ?', 10),
                             ));
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I can't call the method statically. If I try the same thing except starting with 'ArticleCategory->table->delete' I get "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'conditions' in 'where clause"

Comment: It's probably missing an extra array, I can look it up for you, but you could probably find out quicker by just testing it.

Comment: (editted the answer, but you need to test around a bit. This is what the documentation implies, this should at least help you along.